# jQuery $.each - Iterate over an array of objects and select a field for each object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects like below, let's say `arrayValues`:

```
{ field1 : "933", field2 : "something", fieldN: "344" }
{ field1 : "21", field2 : "something", fieldN: "344" }
{ field1 : "34", field2 : "something", fieldN: "344" }
```

Using **jQuery** *foreach* I am trying to get value of `field1` for each object in the array and then add them to another array, let's say `newArray`:

```
var newArray = [];
$.each(arrayValues, function () {   
   newArray.push('what to put here?');
});
```

At the end, `newArray` should contain: `933, 21, 34`

How to do this?

Comment: You could use plain js `map` method here `const newArray = data.map(({field1}) => field1)`

Comment: `arrayValues.map(({field1}) => field1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. jQuery is a framework primarily for amending the DOM. For working with arrays you just need plain old Javascript. As such, simply using `map()` will build the array you require:

```js
let arrayValues = [
  { field1 : "933", field2 : "something", fieldN: "344" },
  { field1 : "21", field2 : "something", fieldN: "344" },
  { field1 : "34", field2 : "something", fieldN: "344" }
]

let newArray = arrayValues.map(o => o.field1);
console.log(newArray);
```

Note that if you would prefer to have the values as integers use `o => parseInt(o.field1, 10)`

If, for whatever reason, you did want to do this in jQuery then you would use `$.map()`:

```
let newArray = $.map(arrayValues, o => o.field1);
```

Comment: I wonder, how many `map()`-posts have in their portfolio guys with 100k+ rep

Comment: More than a few :)

Comment: It works but compiler says error syntax in lambda =>

Comment: It sounds like you need a better compiler that supports ES6. You can use anonymous functions instead: `let newArray = arrayValues.map(function(o) { return o.field1; });`

Comment: Also, once I have newArray I would like to iterate it by applying newArray.forEach but it is not recognized. Is not newArray an array? since I cannot apply forEach.

Comment: `newArray` is absolutely an array, and `forEach()` works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/jdeg73x9/. I'm not sure what the issue is, but something in your code is clearly incorrect

Comment: It works sorry. For some reason intellisense in Visual Studio was failing.

Comment: Ah yeah, I'd suggest disabling intellisense for JS in Visual Studio - it's awful. Works great everywhere else, though.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [{
      field1: "933",
      field2: "something",
      fieldN: "344"
    },
    {
      field1: "21",
      field2: "something",
      fieldN: "344"
    },
    {
      field1: "34",
      field2: "something",
      fieldN: "344"
    }
  ]

  var newArr = [];

  $.each(arr, function(k, v) {
    newArr.push(parseInt(v.field1, 10));
  });
  console.log(newArr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Please review: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

> The `$.each()` function is not the same as `$(selector).each()`, which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The `$.each()` function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array `index` and a corresponding array `value` each time. (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.) The method returns its first argument, the object that was iterated.